# I have express on backend and react on frontend, but i also have admin page working on pug template, how can i run it on one domain

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have express on back-end and react.js on frontend, but i also have admin page with pug view engine, working on express routes, how can i use these in one domain

Comment: Hey here is one boilerplate which help you to resolve the issue. https://github.com/tahnik/react-expressjs

Comment: @Mr.Ratnadeep Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expressjs is composable in a really nice way. You can have a top level express application which routes off to sub-express apps and serve your individual services.

Lets say you want to serve your react frontend from `www.example.com`, your admin (pug views) from `www.example.com/admin`, and you also want to have an api which serves the react frontend at www.example.com/api`.

You would want something a bit like the following code sample which demonstates the composition of express applications. I've not run the code but it should be enough to get you going.

```
// This parent app acts as a parent layer and router
// for all your "sub apps". Any middleware you apply
// to this express app will apply to *all your other
// sub-apps*.
const parentApp = express();

// We now create another express instance, this will
// house the API. It can be in another file and you
// could require in something like "require('api');"
// instead but for brevity we'll keep it all in one
// file.
const apiApp = express();
apiApp.get('/info', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('/info');
    return res.sendStatus(200);
});

// Mount the sub app on the /api route. This means
// you can how hit 'www.example.com/api/info' and
// you'll get back a 200 status code.
parentApp.use('/api', apiApp);

// Now we setup the admin app which we'll add pug
// views into. This is an example so just pretend
// the views exist.
const adminApp = express();
adminApp.set('views', './views');
adminApp.set('view engine', 'pug');
adminApp.get('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    return res.render('login', { title: 'Hey' });
});

// Mount the sub app on the /admin route. This way
// we can hit www.example.com/admin/login to get
// our login page rendered.
parentApp.use('/admin', adminApp);

// Now we create and mount the frontend app that
// serves our fully built react app. You could do
// this with nginx instead but you wanted to do
// it with express so lets do it that way.
const frontendApp = express();
frontendApp.use(express.static('/frontend));

parentApp.use('/', frontendApp);
```

If you'd rather not create yourself a top level express app (and thus creating a bit of a monolith application) then I'd recommend checking out the nginx documentation, or the docs for the HTTP server you use. You should be able to direct requests to particular endpoints to different node applications running on different ports. Static files can then be served natively by your HTTP server. This is definetely a more efficient and elegant approach, but since you asked about express I wanted to showcase that approach primarily.

Comment: @SasunHakobyan I'm afraid I don't understand, could you explain what you're asking a bit more?